# How to save the model output consisting of millions of records in an efficient way?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm testing new models with a data set. Let's say there are 30 features, so in theory I can test `C(30,1) + C(30,2) + ... + C(30,30)` combinations of features. Also let's say there are 10 algorithms (LASSO, XGB, etc.) to be applied for these combinations. With each model trained I'll generate a predicted series over 10 steps.

Altogether the result is expected to be, if put in a dataframe, consisting of millions of columns (and 10 rows), each of which represents a model with a combination of features and an algorithm. I can create a dataframe which appends new column each time a model finishes running.

Because the dataframe format is quite large in capacity, I was wondering if there is a better format to store this result?

Comment: Would it be easier to read if you concatenated in the other direction, i.e. transposing the DataFrame to millions of rows and 10 columns?